# API data is not updating into state variable in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Since I am retrieving data from opentrivia-api ,I wrote entire function outside of useEffect and called it inside the useEffect,but that data is not getting updated into state variable,but I am able to console log on the screen.can anyone solve my problem?

I am expecting solution for this issue.I tried everything,but did got the result.sometimes the data is getting updated into state variable,sometime data is not.

Comment: Question is very unclear. try improving it

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.Can you please suggest me ,how to improve question?

Comment: Probably best if you share some code snippets of what you have done so far

Comment: *sometimes the data is getting updated into state variable,sometime data is not.* - Most likely because you're calling the external API, and it's working asynchronously, not returning the data in time. As others have said, please dd your code to your question.